# gevent timeout error on socket.io connection

Tags: python, socket.io, pyramid, gevent, greenlets

I have a setup containing varnish  nginx and 2 pyramid backends one of them running socket.io app. All the stack works correctly on my local development computer, but i can't get to work the websocket part on the production computer. The traceback of the error that trows the socketio app when a client socket.io tries to connect:

```
[2012-11-20 14:32:00] "GET /socket.io/1/websocket/790777701707 HTTP/1.1" 101 - -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 390, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_socketio-0.3.5_rc2-py2.7.egg/socketio/transports.py", line 226, in send_into_ws
    websocket.send(message)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 350, in send
    return self.send_frame(message, self.OPCODE_TEXT)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 340, in send_frame
    self._write(combined)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 515, in sendall
    data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags, timeout=timeleft)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 483, in send
    return sock.send(data, flags)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
<Greenlet at 0xa449c0c: send_into_ws> failed with error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/greenlet.py", line 390, in run
    result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_socketio-0.3.5_rc2-py2.7.egg/socketio/transports.py", line 230, in read_from_ws
    message = websocket.receive()
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 296, in receive
    result = self._receive()
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 244, in _receive
    frame = self.receive_frame()
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/websocket.py", line 177, in receive_frame
    data0 = read(2)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent_websocket-0.3.6-py2.7.egg/geventwebsocket/python_fixes.py", line 22, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 472, in recv_into
    wait_read(sock.fileno(), timeout=self.timeout, event=self._read_event)
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py", line 169, in wait_read
    switch_result = get_hub().switch()
  File "/var/pyramid/maxserver/eggs/gevent-0.13.8-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/hub.py", line 164, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
timeout: timed out
<Greenlet at 0xa46157c: read_from_ws> failed with timeout
```

I've checked all python packages versions and there are identical in both computers. Also upgraded production computer to libevent 1.4.14b to match local computer.

I don't know which way to go to debug this. Help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure nginx supports websocket yet (nov 2012). You might want to look into that first.

Comment: i'm not using nginx to route we sockets, varnish is on top and pipes websockets directly to the backend. The setup works perfectly in my development env.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the computer where it runs OK is a ubuntu 12.04, and the one that doesn't work is a red hat. Also tested in a mountain lion mac and it works ok. So i've start thinking is a OS related question...